# How to add IDs from one table to another?

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure how to properly go about doing this.

I have my users table with about 500,000 already existing rows.

I'm creating a playlist feature for my music community, so I have a table called playlists.  I'd like to give each of the 500,00 users a default playlist called Favorites.

What is the best way to do this?

Should I call the users table and loop through the data?  Upon each loop, I insert the USERID into the playlists table?  Is there a more efficient process?

Comment: If you have a one-time task to do, you can choose whatever way you want, even a (reasonably) inefficient one... It's a different story if you had to do this all the time...

Comment: Good point, never thought of it like that.  I guess I was just afraid that pulling the entire users table would slow down the database server for a few.

Comment: @pizel, Do you allow users have a several playlists

Comment: Michael, yes.  Users will be able to create additional playlists at any time.  But when we launch the feature, I want each user to automatically have 1 playlist already created (by us) called Favorites.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to run the query

```
UPDATE table_reference
SET column = 'Favorites'
```

There's no WHERE clause so it will apply it to everything.

**Edit**

If you plan on having the default value be 'Favorites' you can set the default value for the field so that you don't run into this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you allow users to have multiple playlists, and that users can not share a common playlist (i.e. not a many to many, so only one user can have the same PlayList)

This means that you'll need to duplicate the Favourites PlayList record for each user, something like:

```
INSERT into PlayLists(UserId, PlayListName)
SELECT u.ID, 'Favorites' FROM Users u
```

You probably also have a many to many table PlayListSong or similar which links songs to the playlist

This would also mean that you need to copy all the links as well - if you can show a bit more about your table design, SO members can help you there as well.